# Как с помощью регулярного выражения выбрать все параграфы, в которых есть конкретное слово?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Допустим есть три параграфа, между которыми может отсутствовать перенос строки:

```
<p>xxx xxx xxx</p><p>xxx yyy xxx</p>

<p>xxx yyy xxx</p>
```

Нужно выбрать те, в которых есть "ууу", используя одно регулярное выражение. Вариант `<p>[\w\W]+?yyy[\w\W]+?<\/p>` - не работает, т.к между `<p>` и `yyy` может находиться `</p>`. Присутствие этого `</p>` нужно как-то исключить.

Comment: А так заходит: <p>[^(<\/p>)]*?yyy[^(<\/p>)]*?<\/p>   - ?

Comment: В `[^]` можно отрицать только одиночные символы. Ты перечислил отрицаемые символы, а не выражение.

Answer (score 0):

> Нужно выбрать те, в которых есть "ууу", используя одно регулярное выражение.

Предложу такой вариант для примера ТС...

```js
const str = `<p>xxx xxx xxx</p><p>xxx yyy xxx1</p>

<p>xxx yyy xxx2</p>`
const re =/<p>[^>]*yyy[^<]*<\/p>/g
console.log(str.match(re))
```

Comment: Такой вариант исключает присутствие тегов внутри `<p></p>`, а оно должно допускаться...

Comment: @YaroslavK, какие ты примеры показал - такие я и использовал... В твою голову мне не залезть.